# Python requests: post JavaScript commands

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to get the content of a site, but this content only appears when I click the 'Chart' link, which is a JavaScript command like this:

```
javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;fcc1$dgrC$ctl02$ctl00&#39;,&#39;&#39;
```

from a element like this:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;fcc1$dgrC$ctl02$ctl00&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Chart</a>
```

This is the site:
[image]

And this is what happens when you click on 'Chart':
[image]

You can see that the link doesn't change, so the only way to get the chart code is by somehow send that JavaScript command

How to find all the chart links?
How can I do a 'virtual click' on the chart links?
And after that, how to get the new html?

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doPostBack just sets the __EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT form fields and submits the form. Those ''s are just quotes BTW.

Comment: What? And how do I use requests to do it?

Comment: It's a POST request. Set __EVENTTARGET to fcc1$dgrC$ctl02$ctl00 and __EVENTARGUMENT to empty string

Answer (score 0):

If those links are indeed "clicked" by javascript listeners, you may have trouble finding a real link to click.

Instead, you could use a tool to simulate a web browser in python and "click" on that link to get to the next page. The best one I've used is Mechanical Soup: https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html.

Comment: Hey Vikas, thks for the sugestion! The 'Chart' link has a pattern:

Comment: The first is 1, the second 2

Comment: <a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;fcc1$dgrC$ctl0(((((2)))))$ctl00&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Chart</a>

Comment: <a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;fcc1$dgrC$ctl0(((((3)))))$ctl00&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Chart</a>

Comment: How do I simulate this click now?

Comment: @Mr.Iago could you send the original url for the website? that will help me figure it out :)